# Negative number if else condition check in javascript

Tags: javascript

For the positive number the if confdition is working fine but its nor executing the negative number condition what be the possible cause of error.

```
//"date is taken as mm/dd/yyyy in input box"
var startDateString = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
var dateToday = new Date();
alert(dateToday);

var myNewDate = process(startDateString);
alert(myNewDate);

var diff = myNewDate - dateToday;
alert(diff);

alert(typeof(diff));

if(diff >= 0){
    alert("selected date is greater than today");
} else {
    alert("selected date is smaller than today");
}
```

**process function**

```
function process(date){
    var parts = date.split("/");
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: What's inside startDateString?

Comment: What is the value of diff and type of diff?

Comment: say a date in format 2/11/2012 ..

Comment: difference I am getting as a number .. if greater date it is positive number else a negative number

Comment: It looks as if you have one too many bracket after your *if* statement...

Comment: it was a typo not actual error .. though updated

Comment: If i passed "2/11/2012" as a startDateString, The function works. Else block fired. Maybe value of startDate element is in wrong format?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if(diff >= 0){
  {
   alert("selected date is greater than today");
   } else {
   alert("selected date is smaller than today"); }
```

to something like:

```
if(diff >= 0){
     alert("selected date is greater than today");
 } else {
   alert("selected date is smaller than today"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For easy date comparison, convert to epoch and compare:

```
   start = startDate.getTime();
   selected = selectedDate.getTime();
   if(selected >= start) {
     // start date was before selected (or dates are equal)
   } else {
     // selected date was before start
   }
```